# $f_x:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique fixed point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous differentiable function. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ consider $f_x:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f_x(y)=f(x,y)$. Suppose there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f_a$ have unique fixed point $b$ ($f_a(b)=b$), and $Df_a(b)$ has no eigenvalue $1$. Prove that, $x$ sufficiently close to $a$, the function $f_x$ has unique fixed point close to $b$.

I know that $Df_a(y_0) = D_Yf(a, y_0)$ only.

Comment: You mean $Df_a(b)$ has no eigenvalue 1 right? Or you do mean $Df_a(y)$ has no eigenvalue 1 for all $y$?

Comment: @MBW I meant $Df_a(b)$ has no eigenvalue 1, sorry.

Comment: No worries! Hint: consider $g(x, y) = f(x, y) - y$

Comment: Further hint: then use the implicit function theorem

Comment: @MBW But why $Df_a(b) $ has no eigenvalue 1 is important?

Comment: If you try to use the implicit function theorem on $g$, a condition on $Dg$  has to be satisfied. This is where the eigenvalue will come in

Comment: @MBW I guess $Df_a(b)$ has no eigenvalue 1 is important to say that $det(Jf_a(b)) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Gabriel: No, that would be about having $0$ as an eigenvalue. Pay attention to the function $g$.